# CentOSのバージョン確認

Tags: linux, centos

ターミナルからlinuxにSSH接続して作業をしています。
CentOSのバージョンを確認しようとしています。
[ここ](https://onoredekaiketsu.com/check-version-of-centos/)を参照し、

```
> cat /etc/redhat-release
```

では `No such file or directory`

```
> rpm –query centos-release
```

では `not installed`

```
> lsb_release -a
```

command not found

という結果になったので

[別サイト](https://eng-entrance.com/linux-centos-version)を参照し

```
> ls --version
```

これで `ls (GNU coreutils) 8.22` と表示されました。

1. linuxにcentOSは自動で入っているものと思っていたのですが違うのでしょうか。
2. また、linuxのバージョン確認の結果はCentOS Linux release 7.6.1810 (Core)のようなものを想定していたのですが、ls (GNU coreutils) 8.22が表示されたということはcentOSでないものが入っているということでしょうか。

上記二点についての回答、参考になるHPございましたらご教授ください。
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 過去の質問では AWS の環境を利用されているようですが、質問の環境は本当に CentOS でしょうか？ / `cat /etc/*-release` を実行するとどうなるでしょうか。

Comment: 上記コマンドを実行したところAmazon Linux AMI release 2018.03と表示されました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

anko さんの [過去の質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/66026) では AWS の環境を利用されていたかと思うので、`/etc/redhat-release` が無いということは恐らく CentOS ではないのだと思います。

代わりに以下のコマンドを実行してみてください。

```
$ cat /etc/*-release
```

代表的なディストリビューションにおけるOSバージョンが記載されたファイル

- `/etc/redhat-release` (RHEL/CentOS)
- `/etc/system-release` (Amazon Linux)
- `/etc/os-release` (Ubuntu)
- `/etc/debian_version` (Debian)

Comment: CentOSではなくAmazon Linuxが入っていることは理解できました。開発する上でAmazon LinuxはOSの一種という認識でいいのでしょうか。

Comment: Amazon Linux も CentOS/RHEL系 に分類される Linux OS の一つです。